# How do I preserve query parameters on a route without a trailing slash on Static Site hosted on S3 and Cloudfront

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I have a statically generated site that I have uploaded to S3 and surface through a Cloudfront distribution - it has a root `index.html` file and several statically generated subpages (e.g. `/donate/index.html`). I have configured the bucket to act as a static host with `index.html` as an index document. And I can visit these pages by visiting the S3 prefix directly, e.g. `/donate/` correctly displays the html in `/donate/index.html`.

Here's the issue - when I link to `/donate?some=query&param=here` S3 automatically 302 redirects these pages without a trailing slash to page with the trailing slash, removing the query parameters which are used by my client-side javascript for lightly tracking state.

For example `/donate?some=query&param=here` 302s to `/donate/` and loses that context, which makes it hard for folks building URLs because they must remember to include the trailing slash (HTTP 302 is also a bad http response if you want web crawlers to remember the new route).

Here's what did not work:

- Configuring Cloudfront to cache routes using query parameters in the distribution's caching policy (Cloudfront > Distribution > Behavior > Edit > Caching Policy)
- Configuring Cloudfront to forward query parameters in the distribution's origin request policy (Cloudfront > Distribution > Behavior > Edit > Origin Request Policy)
- Configuring the S3 bucket to redirect the routes using S3 redirection rules (S3 > Bucket > Properties > Static Web Hosting > Redirection rules)

Answer (score 6):

Here's what finally cracked it - creating a Viewer Request Cloudfront Function to manually check if the path contains neither a file extension nor a trailing slash and adding one in those cases.

```js
function handler (event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    if( !uri.includes('.') && !uri.endsWith('/') ) {
        request.uri = uri + '/'
    }

    return request;
};
```

Create this function in Cloudfront (Cloudfront > Functions > Create Function) and then attach it to your distribution's behavior (Cloudfront > Distribution > Behavior > Edit > Viewer Request > Cloudfront Functions).

Make sure you invalidate the site after the distribution has finished initializing with the new settings and test the new route via CURL - you should see the following behavior change:

```sh
# BEFORE:
curl -v --location http://example.com/donate?please=keep > /dev/null
> GET /donate?please=keep
> RESP 302
> GET /donate/
> RESP 200

# AFTER
curl -v --location http://example.com/donate?please=keep > /dev/null
> GET /donate?please=keep
> RESP 200
```

Is there another way? Will I regret paying for every Cloudfront function invocation? Is there a way to make this happen with purely Cloudfront or S3 policy changes?

Comment: You just made my day

Comment: Note, this solution can be a little dangerous as it will incorrectly redirect requests for objects that don't contain a `.`, and won't redirect for folder structures that do contain dots. The only way to truly know whether the slash should be added would be to actually check the bucket contents to see if the requested key is a file/missing, or a folder containing an index.html (i.e. re-create Amazon's default S3 redirection behaviour). That would probably be best done using an origin request lambda@edge function.